# How to validate Null or Empty cell in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid

I am trying to Validate a cell in DataGrid. This is my first approach to validation. I get some problems with validations as I am new to it.

I have created a class called StringIsNullOrEmptyValidationRule.cs. This class checks if string is null or ""

Here is the code of StringIsNullOrEmptyValidationRule.cs :

```
class StringIsNullOrEmptyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    private string _errorMessage = "";
    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return _errorMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            _errorMessage = value;
        }
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult(true, null);

        if (value == null || ((string)value).Trim() == "")
        {
            result = new ValidationResult(false, this.ErrorMessage);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now I have a datagrid in MainWindow.xaml which is bound to an ObservableCollection called People. Here is my DataGrid :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="maindg" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <Binding Path="LastName">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:StringIsNullOrEmptyValidationRule ErrorMessage="LastName is required" />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Binding="{Binding City}" />

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

**Problem :**

I kept a breakpoint on StringIsNullOrEmptyValidationRule's Validate Method's first line.
When I don't enter any data in a cell under LastName Column, and try to move away from the cell, it does not hit breakpoint, that means validation does not even check.

If I enter some data to the cell under lastName column and then try to move away from the cell, it tries to validates the cell. So it hits the breakpoint.

So, my question is how can I validate NullOrEmpty Cell?

Comment: If anybody thinks that I am using outdated Validation method, then please suggest the new method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ValidationRule works only in case property value is changed. But, when you go from empty cell, value has not changed. Hence, validation rule won't fired in that case.

Implement [**IDataErrorInfo**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) on Person class and do your validation over there something like this:

```
public class Person : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Concat(this[FirstName], " ", this[LastName], " ",
                                 this[City]);
        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string errorMessage = null;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "LastName":
                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastName))
                    {
                        errorMessage = "LastName is required.";
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return errorMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your XAML, you need to set **`ValidatesOnDataError`** property to true for LastName binding:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName, 
                                           ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

Comment: Person class is auto-generated by Entity Framework. Should I still use same method that you suggested?

Comment: Yeah you can use that with classes generated by EF.

Comment: The link [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/07/07/implementing-validation-in-wpf-on-entity-framework-entities.aspx) might be of your interest as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the article. I will read that article as well.

Answer (score 1):

This was retrieved here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykdxa0bc(v=vs.90).aspx

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender,
DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    string headerText = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;

    // Abort validation if cell is not in the CompanyName column. 
    if (!headerText.Equals("CompanyName")) return;

    // Confirm that the cell is not empty. 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText =
            "Company Name must not be empty";
             e.Cancel = true; 
}
```

Basically you can use conditional statements to verify data.

This is obviously the most standard way of validating that something exists in the cell...

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Sorry, I forgot to mention in the question that  I would love to get an answer that is MVVM friendly.

Comment: Also the solution you provided is for Winforms.